# Spying on a service in a method returns Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token in JSON at position 0 thrown

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, karma-jasmine, spy

I am trying to write unit tests for util class in angular

The following test cases gets passed but if i write any test case below this I get following error

**Uncaught : SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0 thrown**

or 
if it is the last test case, I get error like:

HeadlessChrome 79.0.3945 (Windows 10.0.0) ERROR
An error was thrown in afterAll
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0 thrown

**commonUtil.spec.ts**

```
describe('CommonUtil', () => {
    let common: CommonUtil;
    beforeEach(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [RouterTestingModule, HttpClientTestingModule],
        providers: [CommonUtil]
      });
      common = TestBed.get(CommonUtil);
    });
    it('first property set to false', async()=>{
        let data = {login:'google', status:'complete'}
        spyOn(common.userService,'loginDetails').and.returnValue(of(data));
        common.signInUtil.loginType = "";
        common.getLoginType(()=> {});
        expect(common.signInUtil.loginType).toEqual(data.login);
        expect(common.signInUtil.firstUser).toBeFalsy();
    });
});
```

My Util class looks like 
**commonUtil.ts**

```
export class CommonUtil {

    public idType = [
        { key: 'google', value: 'google' },
        { key: 'facebook', value: 'facebook' },
    ];
    constructor(
        public router: Router,
        public http: HttpClient,
        public userService: UserService,
        public signInUtil: SignInUtil) {}

    public getLoginType(_callBack) {
        if(this.signInUtil.loginType === '') {
            const sub = this.userService.loginDetails().subscribe((data: any) => {
                idType.forEach(e => {
                    if (data.login && e.key === data.login && String(data.status) === 'complete') {
                        this.signInUtil.loginType = data.login;
                        this.signInUtil.firstUser = false;
                    } 
                });
            }, error => {});
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You provide a `Router` and a `HttpClient` to the constructor of the class `CommonUtil` but never use them internally. Also `_callBack` of method `getLoginType` is never used. Is there any reason for this?

Comment: there's some other method somewhere, that uses json.parse() on something, that is not a plain value (e.g. object: `JSON.parse({})` will also throw such error). It's not really clear from your example, you should just debug deeper into that to find, what method throws that